# How can I check what value is in an *args function parameter?

Tags: python

I have this function where I receive a variable number of parameters in a *args function parameter and I have to add them. Based on that sum I have to check some conditions:

1. If the sum of them is less than 21, print them
2. If the sum is greater than 21 subtract 10 from the sum for every 11 value and print "no good" if the sum is still greater than 21 after all the substracts
3. If the sum is 21 and I have a 10 value and a 11 value print "Win".

```
def get_hand_value(*args):
    sum=0
    for argument in args:
        sum +=argument
    if(sum < 21):
        print("The value of your hand is {}".format(sum))
    if(sum > 21 and argument == 11):
        sum -=10
        print(sum)
    if(sum>21 and argument != 11):
        print("No Good!")
    if(sum ==21 and argument == 11 and argument == 10):
        print("Win!")    
            
hand_1 = get_hand_value(4,4,4,4)
hand_2 = get_hand_value(11,10)
hand_3 = get_hand_value(11,5,6,4,11,4)
hand_4 = get_hand_value(11,5,6,10)
hand_5 = get_hand_value(10,5,7)
```

This is what I've been able to come up with but after the first hand it just prints "no good"

Comment: `argument` after the loop is the last value from `args`. Checking it doesn't make much sense in your case. You need to go through all the values (with `for` loop for example) and subtract from sum each time you see 11.

Comment: Note that it's generally a bad practice to shadow builtins like [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: What if the sum is exactly 21 and you don't have 10 and 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `argument` after the loop, you're just getting the last argument, you're not checking every argument to see if it's 11. You should check for `11` inside the loop.

Don't use `sum` as a variable name, since it's the name of a built-in function (which you could use to calculate the sum).

Use `elif` when testing mutually exclusive conditions.

```
def get_hand_value(*args):
    total=0
    elevens = 0
    for argument in args:
        total +=argument
        if argument == 11:
            elevens += 1
    if (total < 21):
        print("The value of your hand is {}".format(total))
    elif total > 21:
        total -= elevens * 10
        if total < 21:
            print("The value of your hand is {}".format(total))
        else:
            print("No Good!")
    elif total == 21 and elevens == 1:
        print("Win!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue appears to be the use of `argument` outside of the `for` loop. It will always have the value of the last argument in `args`, and that's not what you intended.

In particular, these conditions:

```
if(sum > 21 and argument == 11):
    sum -=10
    print(sum)

if(sum ==21 and argument == 11 and argument == 10):
    print("Win!")
```

will never be true for the inputs you listed.

Additionally, I would recommend not calling a variable `sum` as that is the name of a built-in function. Ironically, it is the name of the function that would make your life easier here.

```
total = sum(args)
```